# oracle query for get rows whics have null columns from generated query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query which returns some rows with null columns. I wanted only get the rows which have null columns. here is my query

```
SELECT
eofficeuat.gatepass.agent_id,
eofficeuat.cnf_agents.agent_name,
eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.passnumber AS passnumber,
eofficeuat.gatepass.id,
eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.action,
to_char(eofficeuat.gatepass.issuedatetime, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH12:MI:SS PM')  AS issueddatetime

FROM
eofficeuat.gatepass
inner JOIN eofficeuat.cnf_agents ON eofficeuat.gatepass.agent_id = eofficeuat.cnf_agents.agent_id
left JOIN eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle ON eofficeuat.gatepass.id = eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.passnumber

WHERE
trunc((eofficeuat.gatepass.issuedatetime - DATE '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24) - 21602 >= 1569952800
AND trunc((eofficeuat.gatepass.issuedatetime - DATE '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24) < (
    SELECT
        ( sysdate - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 86400000
    FROM
        dual
)

order by eofficeuat.gatepass.issuedatetime desc
```

this showing output like this image in the link
https://gyazo.com/e9e150547b8f104f832cd190ff5392a2

can you please help for this?
thanks

Comment: Why `< (
    SELECT
        ( sysdate - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 86400000
    FROM
        dual
)`? Just write `< ( sysdate - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 86400000`

Comment: Please don't paste link to images. User formatted text for result. This [page](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-flat-file.htm) may help you to format it.

Comment: You WHERE condition looks a bit weird. You can write is simpler like `WHERE TRUNC(eofficeuat.gatepass.issuedatetime) - (6/24) >= to_date('2019-10-01 20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AND TRUNC(eofficeuat.gatepass.issuedatetime) < sysdate`. You don't have to screw with Unix timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't view images, but - if I understood the question, that would be

```
where (   agent_id   is null 
       or agent_name is null
       or passnumber is null
       or ...
     )
```

Comment: I'm glad if it is.

Comment: how can i remove or not showup passnumber columun from my query

Comment: Just omit it from the SELECT statement.